# How to execute a mutation in GraphQL?

Tags: node.js, graphql

In GraphQL we have basically two types of operations: queries and mutations. While queries are well described in the documentation and there are many examples of them, I'm having a hard time to understand how to execute a mutation. Mutations obviously are update methods.

I've created very simple Node.js server:

```
var express = require("express");
var graphqlHTTP = require("express-graphql");
var graphql = require("graphql");
var inMemoryDatabase = require("./inMemoryDatabase").inMemoryDatabase;
var _ = require("lodash-node");

var userType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "User",
  fields: {
    id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
    name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString }
  }
});

var queryType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Query",
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: userType,
      args: {
        id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve: function(parent, { id }) {
        return _.find(inMemoryDatabase, { id: id });
      }
    }
  }
});

var mutationType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutation",
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: userType,
      args: {
        id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
        name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve: function(parent, { id, name }) {
        var index = _.findIndex(inMemoryDatabase, { id: id });
        inMemoryDatabase.splice(index, 1, { id: id, name: name });
        return _.find(inMemoryDatabase, { id: id });
      }
    }
  }
});

var schema = new graphql.GraphQLSchema({
  query: queryType,
  mutation: mutationType
});

var app = express();
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true
  })
);

var port = 9000;
if (process.env.PORT) {
  port = process.env.PORT;
}

app.listen(port);
console.log("Running a GraphQL API server at localhost:" + port + "/graphql");
```

In memory database is just in an array of User objects `{id, name}`:

```
var inMemoryDatabase = [
  {
    id: "31ce0260-2c23-4be5-ab78-4a5d1603cbc8",
    name: "Mark"
  },
  {
    id: "2fb6fd09-2697-43e2-9404-68c2f1ffbf1b",
    name: "Bill"
  }
];

module.exports = {
  inMemoryDatabase
};
```

Executing query to get user by id looks as follows:

```
{
 user(id: "31ce0260-2c23-4be5-ab78-4a5d1603cbc8"){
  name
 }
}
```

How would the mutation changing user name look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Austio's answer was pretty close, but the proper way is:

```
mutation updateUser {
  user(id: "31ce0260-2c23-4be5-ab78-4a5d1603cbc8", name: "Markus") {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey may completely be missing what you are saying, but the way that I look at a mutation is like this

- I get some arguments and a field, that is the same thing as params and a path in rest, with those i do something (in your case lookup the user and update the attribute based on the arguments passed in
- After That, i return something from the resolve function that will fulfill the type you specify in the `type` of the mutation

```js
var mutationType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutation",
  fields: {
    user: {
      // You must return something from your resolve function 
      // that will fulfill userType requirements
      type: userType,
      
      // with these arguments, find the user and update them
      args: {
        id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
        name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString }
      },
      // this does the lookup and change of the data
      // the last step of your result is to return something
      // that will fulfill the userType interface
      resolve: function(parent, { id, name }) {
        // Find the user, Update it
        // return something that will respond to id and name, probably a user object
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Then with that as a context, you pass some arguments and request back a user

```
mutation updateUser {
  user(id: "1", name: "NewName") {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

In a normal production schema you would also normally have something like `errors` that could be returned to convey the different states of the update for failed/not found

Comment: GraphQL has built-in error reporting and you'd typically return a field error if the mutation failed; it wouldn't specifically be encoded in the schema at all.

Comment: HI David, i guess it really depends on the level of errors that you are wanting.  Graphql will provide basic things for like a schema error or invalid query, but if you want more rich errors that would be equivalent to things you get from rest (like 422, or some specific failure event) you have to return a new type for that.  Another specific example is tying into a validation framework like in rails ActiveModel::Validations so that the errors are "better" and more usable by the client.

Comment: In Ruby I tend to use http://graphql-ruby.org/errors/execution_errors.html (which also describes the language-neutral JSON error response format) to return field- or mutation-level errors.

Comment: Ah my bad, updated :)  Sometimes just putting these in graphiql or graphqlplayground will though you the typos

Answer (score 0):

if we connect directly with MongoDB below will help you.

```
mutation {
  
  taskTrackerCreateOne
  (
    record: 
    {
      id:"63980ae0f019789eeea0cd33", 
      name:"63980c86f019789eeea0cda0"
    }
  )
  {
    recordId
  }
}
```